# Can't click a button in Selenium (Python), even though the element was identified correctly

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to click the Finish button on the following document URL:
https://app.pandadoc.com/p/99be757d50d745395babf924f529d9b7d207b7ec?

And while the finish_button.get_attribute('outerHTML') line outputs the correct answer to find the button (hence it's correctly identified), the program does not returns any errors and also doesn't actually click the button.

```
print(f"Requesting {document_URL}")
driver.get(document_URL)

        
print("Waiting for page to load...")
time.sleep(30)

document_detail_page = driver.current_url
print(f'Current page url: {document_detail_page}')

print("Accepting Cookies")
accept_cookies = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'onetrust-accept-btn-handler')
accept_cookies.click()

time.sleep(15)            

print("Finding Finish Button to click")
finish_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Finish"]')
print(f"HTML of button: {finish_button.get_attribute('outerHTML')}")`
```

I've tried the following 3 approaches, none of which worked:

```
finish_button.click()

ActionChains(driver).click(finish_button).perform()

webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(finish_button).click(finish_button).perform()
```

`

EDIT: Someone seems to have clicked the link and hit the button manually (or figured out the solution but didn't post it here). The same goes for the now visible "Download" button that seems to have the same properties.

Comment: _doesn't actually click the button_ How do you know it isn't clicked?  Presumably you're expecting to see some behavior, which doesn't happen.  What behavior is that?

Comment: I don't see a Finish button on that page...

Comment: It's only a "Download" button now (I shared a live doc, so someone clicked the "Finish" button), but the principle is the same. The behavior that's missing is that the document should be closed for signing (similar to a Docusign).

Answer (score 1):

All I see is a `Download` button. Here's a Python script that clicks it with [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) (and verifies the download) after `pip install seleniumbase` and running with `python`:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(browser="chrome", headless=False) as sb:
    sb.open("https://app.pandadoc.com/p/99be757d50d745395babf924f529d9b7d207b7ec")
    sb.click('button[color="primary"]')
    sb.assert_downloaded_file("NDA.pdf")  # Searching ./downloaded_files/
    sb.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Is it possible to rewrite this with my existing Selenium Webdriver running? I'm not an expert (someone else wrote this code for me) so I am trying to plug and play where possible, but I hit a roadblock with this.

This is my driver:

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options) with a bunch of headers and other settings I don't fully understand.

Comment: SeleniumBase simplifies regular Selenium so that you don't have to worry about driver instantiation, etc, and those other headers & settings that aren't easily understood. But if you just want the selector, that's ``'button[color="primary"]'`` with ``By.CSS_SELECTOR``.

Comment: Thank you! The script I initially had does recognize the correct button (I used that last print function to check this - it returns the full HTML of the button). However, the button.click() or any of the other functions I tried didn't actually click it. I'm not sure what's keeping it from clicking the button.

Here is another link that has the Finish button still active: https://app.pandadoc.com/p/ed454f9dd75f3f6702dff775fc542e41460c8ecf?

Comment: Same selector as the other button. Use `By.CSS_SELECTOR` with `'button[color="primary"]'`. Eg. `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[color="primary"]').click()`, or try the script in the solution.

Comment: I just ran that exact line of code and unfortunately, like my other attempts with the .click() function, it did not actually click the button.